# Two for loops in a function

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I want to count specific words in a string (sentence) using a function. first  I want to get rid of all special characters in the string and then count the number of a specific word (in this case te word test).

Both for loops work well apart from each other, but I can't get it to work in one function. after trying for an hour or so, my question to you: there must be a very simple solution... many thanks

```
def BestCount(st):
    #strip special caracters.
    st_new=''
    for x in st:
        if x.isalnum():
            st_new +=x 
        #use the stripped string to count de number of word: best.
        count = 0
        for word in st_new.lower().split():
            if word == 'test':
                count +=1
        return count
```

Trying my function:

```
BestCount('this is a test test.')
Output: 0
```

many thanks again!

Comment: please align the loops correctly

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese I think that's the issue they are having

Comment: nope, there is more

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean there is more? Edit: I see that there's another issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `x.isalnum()`, spaces are neglected , so the `.split()` function doesn't work ( ie, the string isin't splited). So instead, allow spaces too, and also, align the functions properly:

```
def BestCount(st):
    #strip special caracters.
    st_new=''
    for x in st:
        if x.isalnum() or x.isspace():
            st_new +=x 
    count = 0
    for word in st_new.lower().split():
      if word == 'test':
        count +=1
    return count
print(BestCount('this is a test test.'))
```

gives:

```
2
```

Here is a run of the code: [Trinket](https://trinket.io/embed/python/2ef38bb459)